# How to handle invalid URL parameters with ui-router in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, url-routing, state, angular-ui-router

I am transitioning from state A to state planManager/:param where param can only be param1, param2 or param3. I use this code to navigate:

```
<a href ui-sref=".({state: 'param1'})" ng-click="updateResize()" ui-sref-opts="{reloadOnSearch: false}">GO TO Param1 State</a>
```

Now if somehow the user hits the url

> parentState/planManager/invalidParam

, I want to redirect to

> parentState/planManager/param1

In my planManager module, I do this using:

```
angular.module( 'parentState.planManager', [
  'ui.router'
])
.config(function config( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider["state"]( 'planManager', {
    url: '/planManager/:state',
    views: {
      "main": {
        controller: 'planManagerControl',
        templateUrl: 'planManager/planManager.tpl.html'
      }
    },
    data:{ pageTitle: 'Plan Manager', currentState: 'planManager'},
    resolve:{
         validState: ['$stateParams','localStorageService','$urlRouter',function($stateParams,localStorageService,$urlRouter){
          if($stateParams["state"]!="buy" && $stateParams["state"]!="audience" && $stateParams["state"]!="campaign"){
            $stateParams["state"]="buy";
          }

          return true;
         }]
        }
  });
  $urlRouterProvider.when('/planManager/', '/planManager/buy');
  $urlRouterProvider.when('/planManager', '/planManager/buy');
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/planManager/buy');
})
```

This doesn't seem to work. What is wrong here? Should I be using regex of some sort?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Added a 

$urlRouter.sync();

after 

$stateParams["state"]="buy";